# Не выходит создать объект, состоящий из своиств другого объекта

Tags: typescript

```
type someType = {
    a: string,
    b: boolean,
    c: number
}

const fields: (keyof someType)[] = ['a', 'b', 'c']

const foo: someType = {
    a: '',
    b: false,
    c: 5
}

const bar: Partial<someType> = {}

for (const field of fields ) {
    if (field in foo) {
        bar[field] = foo[field]
    }
}
```

При присвоении `bar[field] = foo[field]` получаю ошибку

> Тип "string | number | boolean" не может быть назначен для типа "undefined".
> Тип "string" не может быть назначен для типа "undefined".ts(2322)

Объясните пожалуйста, что не так и как надо.

Answer (score 0):

Я внес некоторые изменения, проблема в том что ты не можешь использовать переменную у которой тип например `string` как индекс для объекта. По этому тебе надо `убедить` TypeScript в том что эта переменная может быть использована как индекс, вот самый быстрый способ.

```
type someType = {
    a: string,
    b: boolean,
    c: number
}

const fields: (keyof someType)[] = ['a', 'b', 'c']

const foo: someType = {
    a: '',
    b: false,
    c: 5
}

const bar: Partial<someType> = {}

for (const field of fields ) {
    if (field in foo) {
        bar[field as keyof typeof fields] = foo[field]
    }
}
```